# configure paw server on Android board

Tags: android

I have just downloaded PAW server on my android device.
But the problem is when I reboot the board , the data that I have copied into /sdcard/paw/html/ directory is getting removed. I can not see my copied data into that folder. Why this is happening??

And also the php plugin is removed from paw server.

Is there any problem if I do not stop the PAW server and reboot the board? Because the problem I am facing is when I reboot the board without stopping the PAW server , its getting corrupted and I am not able to open it(use it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PAW server is very easy to use and works fantastic.And Works great.
The problem was in copying the files in "paw" folder and problem was with Sdcard (it is bit old so) I changed my sdcard and copying my data into "paw" directory and yipeeee it worked.

Comment: My Resource like images are not loading paw server. i have placed all the resources in sdcard/paw/html. where am i wrong?